# Error in trying to convert dataset to time series

Tags: r, time-series

I'm working on a dataset with monthly air pollution data for a city in china. This is what it looks like.(all numericals are of class 'integer')

```
head(fuzhou)
 Month PM2.5 SO2 NO2 PM10   MCR MMMT MMH

1 2014-08    25   6  31   58 363.6 34.5  77

2 2014-09    25   4  23   56  42.0 33.2  72

3 2014-10    33   7  25   70   3.6 28.1  64
etc etc....
```

I converted the month data to date variable using

```
fuzhou$Month = as.Date(as.yearmon(fuzhou$Month, "%Y-%m"))
```

Now i need to make different time series' for each data
I got the PM2.5 series from `pm25 = ts_ts(ts_long(fuzhou[1:2]))`

But I can't seem to make new series' using the other data.
I tried `so2 = ts_ts(ts_long(fuzhou[1,3]))` but it returned an error `Error in relevant_class(x) : ts_boxable(x) is not TRUE`

I tried to make a new dataset using `rawso2 = c(fuzhou$Month, fuzhou$SO2)` but that didn't work either (`Error in as.Date.numeric(e) : 'origin' must be supplied`)

So how do I make time series' for the other six parameters?
The desired result is to get time series for each of them of class "ts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a zoo object, `z`, and from that a ts object `tt` whose columns are the individual series so `z$SO2` or `z[, "SO2"]` is an individual zoo series and `tt[, "SO2"]` is an individual ts series.  Generally it's a better idea to keep the series together and not create a bunch of variables in your workspace but if you want to do it anyways then the `for` statement at the end will create a ts variable for each column.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(fuzhou, FUN = as.yearmon)
tt <- as.ts(z); tt
##          PM2.5 SO2 NO2 PM10   MCR MMMT MMH
## Aug 2014    25   6  31   58 363.6 34.5  77
## Sep 2014    25   4  23   56  42.0 33.2  72
## Oct 2014    33   7  25   70   3.6 28.1  64

for(nm in colnames(tt)) assign(nm, tt[, nm])
```

### Note

We assume the input is the following data frame shown in reproducible form.

```
fuzhou <- structure(list(Month = c("2014-08", "2014-09", "2014-10"), PM2.5 = c(25L, 
25L, 33L), SO2 = c(6L, 4L, 7L), NO2 = c(31L, 23L, 25L), PM10 = c(58L, 
56L, 70L), MCR = c(363.6, 42, 3.6), MMMT = c(34.5, 33.2, 28.1
), MMH = c(77L, 72L, 64L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```